# Disable all the date before today From Aspx in asp.net WebForms

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I want to Disable all dates before today from aspx in asp.net webforms. i can do it with jquery but i need it to do from aspx ! Help me!
im trying to achieve this 
[image]

Comment: What is a scriptlet? Any code you can show us?

Comment: In JavaServer Pages (JSP) technology, a scriptlet is a piece of Java-code embedded in the HTML-like JSP code. The scriptlet is everything inside the <%  %> tags. Between these the user can add any valid Scriplet i.e. any valid Java Code.
By the way <%  %> is called in ASP.NET?

Comment: Why can't you just put the jQuery code to do it directly on your page?